# If I changed my MAC address, does it effect my ethernet to internet in anyway?

Tags: networking, cmd.exe, ethernet, arp, internet-speed

I'm on a public network and I can connect to WiFi for free but to use internet I need to put username and password.

And when my card ended I usually see who's the network with me like I'm doing right now. But the problem is the Internet start to be so slow without reason but when I return to the original MAC address the speed of internet so back to be so high.

So I want to know is there any why to change my MAC Address without getting low internet speed?

The way I change my MAC address is:
from : registry editor
this bath :

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}\0009
```

And create new -> string value and name it "NetworkAddress"
with value:

> `3E95277DB5AR` < the MAC address I get it from `arp -a`

Comment: Where exactly "from `arp -a`"? Which device's MAC address are you copying?

Comment: any dynamic MAC address I found ,I replace main with it :)
it works and I can use the internet for free but it's so slow !!!!!

Comment: MAC addresses are not dynamic. There are phones and wifi cards that use random *per connection* addresses but they are not changed on the fly. In theory a MAC address is burned into the network card itself and many switches and routers use it to decide what port they send data to on a local network. By using a MAC address from another machine on your network you are confusing the logic so the wifi card has no clue whether the data it is receiving is for a connection it initiated or for some other card with the same address.

Answer (score 3):

> any dynamic MAC address I found ,I replace main with it :) it works and I can use the internet for free but it's so slow !!!!!

Then, most likely, it's slow because you're trying to use a MAC address **that another device is already using.** If you're both on the same access point, then the other person gets kicked off Wi-Fi when you connect, their device immediately tries to reconnect, which causes *you* to disconnect, and so on, and so on.

If you happen to be on two different access points, then they both accept the connections but instead the same is happening inside the switches that connect them together; as both of you send packets, the MAC address entry keeps flipping between the two Ethernet ports over and over, resulting in packets being delivered to the wrong host and then having to be retransmitted.

This trick only works if you connect at a different time than the person you're stealing access from.

Comment: thank you very much ♥

Answer (score 0):

There are apps to do so programmatically, e.g., [MacShift](https://www.nayuki.io/page/macshift-nayukis-version) and [Technetium MAC Address Changer](https://technitium.com/tmac/). Note that I've not tried either Check any app at [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) before using.

However, you are **asking two different questions.**

- Is there a way to change my MAC address? That was answered here.
- Will that affect my internet speed? That is unanswerable -- why should your internet speed depend on MAC address??

Comment: I don't know " why should your internet speed depend on MAC address " but when I return to original MAC address the speed is great !